# Model error in View in laravel5.3

Tags: model, laravel-5.3

I have three models:

1. Article
2. Address
3. Users

In Users model i have two function for accessing article and address values.but when i access table content using model in view it give me error message that $Users is undefined.

Comment: Post function of your controller please

Comment: Post also the loop blade that you are using in the view

Comment: To give you a great answer, it might help us if you have a glance at [ask] if you haven't already. It might be also useful if you could provide a [mcve].